# magento2 shipping method :Table Rates import issue

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta, file-upload

Right now I am trying to import table rates, shipping method rates in Magento 2 in **windows environment**.But whenever I am trying to import it throw me error like

`The file "C:/Windows/Temp/E:/wamp/tmp/php9B36.tmp" doesn't exist`

I have already set `upload_tmp_dir` to `E:/wamp/tmp`, I don't know why it appends C drive directory.

Can anyone drive me to right direction?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the default upload file temp directory set in the `php.ini` file by WAMP is an ok location, but it does not work. So, you need to change this setting.

Find this line:

`upload_tmp_dir = "E:/wamp/tmp"`

Change it to this:

`upload_tmp_dir = "C:/Windows/Temp"`

Now, save the file, restart apache so the new settings will take effect, and file upload will now work for you.

> Generally this issue happened into Windows environment only (WAMP &
>   XAMPP). for `upload_tmp_dir` or `session.save_path`.
>
> At front-end the same setting worked but not at backend.
>
> In Magento 1.x.x it was working fine for both end.
>
> Here, I hope that, proper reason from Superiors.

Comment: Why the upload_tmp_dir is for C drive ? What it will be in production environment ? Can we change tablerates import path to Magento directory ? Just like w do for catalog products import which is `pub/media/import`

Comment: Yes, you may to set the path as per the OS environment.