# Table Rate Import Error - XAMPP - Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, table-rates

I'm trying to import table rates , weight vs destination into Magento 2.2.3 but it comes up with the following error:

**The file "C:/Windows/Temp/E:/xampp/tmp/php9B36.tmp" doesn't exist**

I tried this solution below, but all it does is change the error message to:

**The file "C:/Windows/Temp/C:/xampp/tmp/php10B39.tmp" doesn't exist**

[magento2 shipping method :Table Rates import issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87801/magento2-shipping-method-table-rates-import-issue)

How can I fix it?